# у меня неправильно позиционируется надпись в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#window options
window = Tk()
window.title('picture viewer(v0.04alpha)')
window.geometry('800x600')
window['bg'] = 'grey'

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
#img
pil_image = Image.open("E:/11.jpg")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
image_sprite = Label(window, image=image)
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=8)

label_pic_name = Label(window, text='<<тут будет назв картинки>>')
label_pic_name.grid(row=3, column=2)

#bottons_top
frame_top = Frame(window, width=100, height=100)
frame_top.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn1 = Button(frame_top, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn2 = Button(frame_top, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn3 = Button(frame_top, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)

btn4 = Button(frame_top, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn4.grid(row=0, column=4)

#bottons_side
frame_side = Frame(window)
frame_side.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
btn11 = Button(frame_side, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn11.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn22 = Button(frame_side, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn22.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn33 = Button(frame_side, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             
             )
btn33.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn44 = Button(frame_side, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn44.grid(row=4, column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

[но у меня выходит такой результат][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. эта строчка кода работает не так как надо

```
label_pic_name = Label(window, text='<<тут будет назв картинки>>')
label_pic_name.grid(row=3, column=2)
```

(надпись должна быть под картинкой) так в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну у вас картинка в колонке 1, а надпись вы поставили в колонку 2, естественно надпись оказывается правее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#window options
window = Tk()
window.title('picture viewer(v0.04alpha)')
window.geometry('800x600')
window['bg'] = 'grey'

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
#img
pil_image = Image.open("lena.jpg")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
image_sprite = Label(window, image=image)
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=8)

label_pic_name = Label(window, text='<< lena.jpg >>')
#label_pic_name.grid(row=3, column=2)                           # ---
label_pic_name.grid(row=2, column=1)                            # +++

#bottons_top
frame_top = Frame(window, width=100, height=100)
frame_top.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn1 = Button(frame_top, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn2 = Button(frame_top, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn3 = Button(frame_top, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)

btn4 = Button(frame_top, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn4.grid(row=0, column=4)

#bottons_side
frame_side = Frame(window)
frame_side.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
btn11 = Button(frame_side, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn11.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn22 = Button(frame_side, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn22.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn33 = Button(frame_side, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             
             )
btn33.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn44 = Button(frame_side, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn44.grid(row=4, column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пасиб) а как, кстати, убрать белую обводку вокруг фотографии?

Comment: @user449662  пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.